# I am getting following errors while running my node.js script

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error on my pm2 console. Can anyone please suggest me the changes that need to be done in my code? Thank you.

```
server-0 (err):     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
server-0 (err):     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
server-0 (err):     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
server-0 (err): Error: read ECONNRESET
server-0 (err):     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
server-0 (err):     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:563:26)
server-0 (err): Error: read ECONNRESET
server-0 (err):     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
server-0 (err):     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:563:26)
server-0 (err): Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (XMPP authentication failure)
server-0 (err):     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:163:17)
server-0 (err):     at Client.<anonymous> (/ccs-node/node_modules/node-gcm-ccs/node-gcm-ccs.js:56:10)
server-0 (err):     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
server-0 (err):     at Client.emit (events.js:188:7)
server-0 (err):     at Client._handleAuthState (/ccs-node/node_modules/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js:298:10)
server-0 (err):     at Client._handleStanza (/ccs-node/node_modules/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js:234:12)
server-0 (err):     at Client.onStanza (/ccs-node/node_modules/node-xmpp-client/lib/Client.js:222:8)
server-0 (err):     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
server-0 (err):     at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
server-0 (err):     at Connection.onStanza (/ccs-node/node_modules/node-xmpp-core/lib/Connection.js:369:10)
```

Comment: @Dejan How would posting the cost help isolate a protocol error?

Answer (score 0):

> "ECONNRESET" means the other side of the TCP conversation abruptly
>   closed its end of the connection. This is most probably due to one or
>   more application protocol errors. You could look at the API server
>   logs to see if it complains about something

.

What could also be the case: at random times, the other side is overloaded and simply kills the connection as a result. If that's the case, depends on what you're connecting to exactly…

But one thing's for sure: you indeed have a read error on your TCP connection which causes the exception. You can see that by looking at the error code you posted in your edit, which confirms it.